# When exactly is it leak safe to use (anonymous) inner classes?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, inner-classes

I have been reading some articles on memory leaks in Android and watched this interesting video from Google I/O [on the subject](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk).

Still, I don't fully understand the concept, and especially when it is safe or dangerous to user **inner classes inside an Activity**.

This is what I understood:

A memory leak will occur if an instance of an inner class survives longer than its outer class (an Activity).
-> **In which situations can this happen?**

In this example, I suppose there is no risk of leak, because there is no way the anonymous class extending `OnClickListener` will live longer than the activity, right?

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_generic);
    Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_ok);
    TextView titleTv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_generic_title);

    // *** Handle button click
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    titleTv.setText("dialog title");
    dialog.show();
```

Now, is this example dangerous, and why?

```
// We are still inside an Activity
_handlerToDelayDroidMove = new Handler();
_handlerToDelayDroidMove.postDelayed(_droidPlayRunnable, 10000);

private Runnable _droidPlayRunnable = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        _someFieldOfTheActivity.performLongCalculation();
    }
};
```

I have a doubt regarding the fact that understanding this topic has to do with understanding in detail what is kept when an activity is destroyed and re-created.

Is it?

Let say I just changed the orientation of the device (which is the most common cause of leaks). When `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` will be called in my `onCreate()`, will this restore the values of the fields (as they were before orientation change)? Will this also restore the states of inner classes?

I realize my question is not very precise, but I'd really appreciate any explanation that could make things clearer.

Comment: [**This blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/activitys-threads-memory-leaks.html) and [**this blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) have some good information about memory leaks and inner classes. :)

Comment: Totally recomended your posts @AlexLockwood :) thx!

Answer (score 699, accepted):

What you are asking is a pretty tough question. While you may think it is just one question, you are actually asking several questions at once. I'll do my best with the knowledge that I have to cover it and, hopefully, some others will join in to cover what I may miss.

**Nested Classes: Introduction**

As I'm not sure how comfortable you are with OOP in Java, this will hit a couple of basics. A nested class is when a class definition is contained within another class. There are basically two types: Static Nested Classes and Inner Classes. The real difference between these are:

- Static Nested Classes:

  - Are considered "top-level".
  - Do not require an instance of the containing class to be constructed.
  - May not reference the containing class members without an explicit reference.
  - Have their own lifetime.
- Inner Nested Classes:

  - Always require an instance of the containing class to be constructed.
  - Automatically have an implicit reference to the containing instance.
  - May access the container's class members without the reference.
  - Lifetime is *supposed* to be no longer than that of the container.

**Garbage Collection and Inner Classes**

Garbage Collection is automatic but tries to remove objects based on whether it thinks they are being used. The Garbage Collector is pretty smart, but not flawless. It can only determine if something is being used by whether or not there is an active reference to the object.

The real issue here is when a inner class has been kept alive longer than its container. This is because of the implicit reference to the containing class. The only way this can occur is if an object outside of the containing class keeps a reference to the inner object, without regard to the containing object.

This can lead to a situation where the inner object is alive (via reference) but the references to the containing object has already been removed from all other objects. The inner object is, therefore, keeping the containing object alive because it will *always* have a reference to it. The problem with this is that unless it is programmed, there is no way to get back to the containing object to check if it is even alive.

The most important aspect to this realization is that it makes no difference whether it is in an Activity or is a drawable. You will ***always*** have to be methodical when using inner classes and make sure that they never outlive objects of the container. Luckily, if it isn't a core object of your code, the leaks may be small in comparison. Unfortunately, these are some of the hardest leaks to find, because they are likely to go unnoticed until many of them have leaked.

**Solutions: Inner Classes**

- Gain temporary references from the containing object.
- Allow the containing object to be the only one to keep long-lived references to the inner objects.
- Use established patterns such as the Factory.
- If the inner class does not require access to the containing class members, consider turning it into a static class.
- Use with caution, regardless of whether it is in an Activity or not.

**Activities and Views: Introduction**

Activities contain a lot of information to be able to run and display. Activities are defined by the characteristic that they must have a View. They also have certain automatic handlers. Whether you specify it or not, the Activity has an implicit reference to the View it contains.

In order for a View to be created, it must know where to create it and whether it has any children so that it can display. This means that every View has an reference to the Activity (via `getContext()`). Moreover, every View keeps references to its children (i.e. `getChildAt()`). Finally, each View keeps a reference to the rendered Bitmap that represents its display.

Whenever you have a reference to an Activity (or Activity Context), this means that you can follow the ENTIRE chain down the layout hierarchy. This is why memory leaks regarding Activities or Views are such a huge deal. It can be a **ton** of memory being leaked all at once.

**Activities, Views and Inner Classes**

Given the information above about Inner Classes, these are the most common memory leaks, but also the most commonly avoided. While it is desirable to have an inner class have direct access to an Activities class members, many are willing to just make them static to avoid potential issues. The problem with Activities and Views goes much deeper than that.

**Leaked Activities, Views and Activity Contexts**

It all comes down to the Context and the LifeCycle. There are certain events (such as orientation) that will kill an Activity Context. Since so many classes and methods require a Context, developers will sometimes try to save some code by grabbing a reference to a Context and holding onto it. It just so happens that many of the objects we have to create to run our Activity have to exist outside of the Activity LifeCycle in order to allow the Activity to do what it needs to do. If any of your objects happen to have a reference to an Activity, its Context, or any of its Views when it is destroyed, you have just leaked that Activity and its entire View tree.

**Solutions: Activities and Views**

- Avoid, at all costs, making a Static reference to a View or Activity.
- All references to Activity Contexts should be short lived (the duration of the function)
- If you need a long-lived Context, use the Application Context (`getBaseContext()` or `getApplicationContext()`). These do not keep references implicitly.
- Alternatively, you may limit the destruction of an Activity by overriding Configuration Changes. However, this does not stop other potential events from destroying the Activity. While you *can* do this, you may still want to refer to the above practices.

**Runnables: Introduction**

Runnables are actually not that bad. I mean, they *could* be, but really we've already hit most of the danger zones. A Runnable is an asynchronous operation that performs a task independant from the thread it was created on. Most runnables are instantiated from the UI thread. In essence, using a Runnable is creating another thread, just slightly more managed. If you class a Runnable like a standard class and follow the guidelines above, you should run into few problem. The reality is that many developers do not do this.

Out of ease, readability and logical program flow, many developers utilize Anonymous Inner Classes to define their Runnables, such as the example you create above. This results in an example like the one you typed above. An Anonymous Inner Class is basically a discrete Inner Class. You just don't have to create a whole new definition and simply override the appropriate methods. In all other respects it is a Inner Class, which means that it keeps an implicit reference to its container.

**Runnables and Activities/Views**

Yay! This section can be short! Due to the fact that Runnables run outside of the current thread, the danger with these comes to long running asynchronous operations. If the runnable is defined in an Activity or View as an Anonymous Inner Class OR nested Inner Class, there are some very serious dangers. This is because, as previously stated, it ***has*** to know who its container is. Enter the orientation change (or system kill). Now just refer back to the previous sections to understand what just happened. Yes, your example is quite dangerous.

**Solutions: Runnables**

- Try and extend Runnable, if it doesn't break the logic of your code.
- Do your best to make extended Runnables static, if they must be nested classes.
- If you must use Anonymous Runnables, avoid creating them in ***any*** object that has a long-lived reference to an Activity or View that is in use.
- Many Runnables could just as easily have been AsyncTasks. Consider using AsyncTask as those are VM Managed by default.

**Answering the Final Question**
Now to answer the questions that were not *directly* addressed by the other sections of this post. You asked "When can an object of an inner class survive longer than its outer class?" Before we get to this, let me reemphasize: though you are right to worry about this in Activities, it can cause a leak anywhere. I shall provide a simple example (without using an Activity) just to demonstrate.

Below is a common example of a basic factory (missing the code).

```
public class LeakFactory
{//Just so that we have some data to leak
    int myID = 0;
// Necessary because our Leak class is an Inner class
    public Leak createLeak()
    {
        return new Leak();
    }

// Mass Manufactured Leak class
    public class Leak
    {//Again for a little data.
       int size = 1;
    }
}
```

This is a not as common example, but simple enough to demonstrate. The key here is the constructor...

```
public class SwissCheese
{//Can't have swiss cheese without some holes
    public Leak[] myHoles;

    public SwissCheese()
    {//Gotta have a Factory to make my holes
        LeakFactory _holeDriller = new LeakFactory()
    // Now, let's get the holes and store them.
        myHoles = new Leak[1000];

        for (int i = 0; i++; i<1000)
        {//Store them in the class member
            myHoles[i] = _holeDriller.createLeak();
        }

    // Yay! We're done! 

    // Buh-bye LeakFactory. I don't need you anymore...
    }
}
```

Now, we have Leaks, but no Factory. Even though we released the Factory, it will remain in memory because every single Leak has a reference to it. It doesn't even matter that the outer class has no data. This happens far more often than one might think. We don't need the creator, just its creations. So we create one temporarily, but use the creations indefinitely.

Imagine what happens when we change the constructor just slightly.

```
public class SwissCheese
{//Can't have swiss cheese without some holes
    public Leak[] myHoles;

    public SwissCheese()
    {//Now, let's get the holes and store them.
        myHoles = new Leak[1000];

        for (int i = 0; i++; i<1000)
        {//WOW! I don't even have to create a Factory... 
        // This is SOOOO much prettier....
            myHoles[i] = new LeakFactory().createLeak();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, every single one of those new LeakFactories has just been leaked. What do you think of that? Those are two very common examples of how a inner class can outlive an outer class of any type. If that outer class had been an Activity, imagine how much worse it would have been.

**Conclusion**

These list the primarily known dangers of using these objects inappropriately. In general, this post should have covered most of your questions, but I understand it was a loooong post, so if you need clarification, just let me know. As long as you follow the above practices, you will have very little worry of leakage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear and detailed answer. I just don't get what you mean by "many developers utilize closures to define their Runnables"

Comment: Closures in Java are Anonymous Inner Classes, like the Runnable you describe. Its a way to utilize a class (almost extend it) without writing a defined Class that extends Runnable. It's called a closure because it is "a closed class definition" in that it has its own closed memory space within the actual containing object.

Comment: Enlightening write-up! One remark regarding terminology: There is no such thing as a _static inner class_ in Java. ([Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)). A nested class is either _static_ or _inner_, but cannot be both at the same time.

Comment: While that is technically correct, Java allows you to define static classes inside static classes. The terminology is not for my benefit, but for the benefit of others who do not understand the technical semantics. This is why it is first mentioned that they are "top-level". The Android developer docs also use this terminology, and this is for people looking at Android development, so I thought it better to keep consistency.

Comment: Awesome post. Could you please explain "Many Runnables could just as easily have been AsyncTasks. Consider using AsyncTask as those are VM Managed by default."? Why can AsyncTask solve the problem? Is there an example. Thanks

Comment: An AsyncTask is an asynchronous operation (generally short-lived). It is outside of the scope of this question, so it would be best if you did some research on AsyncTask and how to use it.

Comment: I disagree on a point here if a thread is created which only does some background task it will never leak activity reference it will only leak its reference since it's not updating any UI and it's not holding Looper in any way

Comment: Why asynctask leaks memory is because it has a reference of Looper in it

Comment: If the background task is programmed properly, you are correct. If it is not, then it can certainly leak UI references, even if it is not updating UI. This specific point is directly addressed even in the document provided by the OP.

Comment: What do you mean AsyncTask has a reference of Looper? AsyncTasks keep no such reference. They may only be run once per task. Afterwards, they must be discarded. In fact, this is the preferred method, from many sources for many years for doing very short-lived tasks.

Comment: @FuzzicalLogic im guessing a leak will also occur if an outer class holds references to its inner class instances? would need to do some form of cleanup before the outer class loses all references to it i assume. Eg, a list adapter inner class, and an outer class holding a reference to an instance of the adapter (in this case both the outer and inner classes are leaking, because of reference cycle)

Comment: @Fonix That depends on whether you are speaking of the outer class itself, or an instance of the outer class. In the first case, this could potentially create a leak, but most GCs will resolve the issue when the application ends. In the latter, leaks will not be created unless there were violations within the inner class. Given the specific question, I'm not sure if it would be worthwhile to address in this post.

Comment: "Many Runnables could just as easily have been AsyncTasks. Consider using AsyncTask as those are VM Managed by default." But if we have inner non static `AsyncTask`, same problems that of `Runnable` would apply. Am I correct?

Comment: At the time this was written `AsyncTask` was self-managed (i.e. GC'd). So, it avoided most of the problems that misusing `Runnable`. AFAIK, that hasn't changed.

Comment: ['Static inner' is a contradiction in terms](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3), and 'non-static inner' is therefore a tautology. Terminology here is completely incorrect. Please fix it.

Comment: @FuzzicalLogic, thanks for the post, may I have a question? I think when there is no reference to `SwissCheese` instance once it has done its work, the Factory will be able to be GCed, and the memory leak will be not an issue any longer, am I right?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the nice comments and the long term support and cleanup of the answer. @Lii: Thank you for fixing the terms, as android docs fixed them a bit ago and they were no longer necessary for newcomers to android specifically. This should probably be wiki now, so I'm going to move it over there.

Comment: @FuzzicalLogic, Java has no closures. It has lambdas, big big difference. And the name does not come from "a closed class definition" in that it has its own closed memory space within the actual containing object.`` They are named closures because "they close over" as in capture, the scope around them. Unlike lambdas, closures can modify the surrounding variables. E.g. as in Groovy or Scala. Sorry for the nitpicking :D

Comment: @AngelO'Sphere This is been wiki for several months. As originally indicated, the terminology used in the answer was used based on the inaccurate usage in the original Android docs and tutorials as this is an Android-centric answer. Since the answer was originally written, Google has updated their docs/tutorials to be more in line with Java's definitions. And as such, many other individuals have been editing and fixing the terminology appropriately. They will continue to do so, as I have moved on from this answer quite some time ago. Keep in mind, this answer is more than 7yrs old, IIRC

Comment: Yes, I understand, that is why I appologizerd for my nitpicking, hehe. Your example btw. is quite funny :D

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Knowing that activities can be killed and re-created "randomly", this warning finally  makes sense to me

Comment: Thanks. Could you add an example in which the inner nested class will work without resulting in memory leak? After reading this answer, I am afraid of using any inner nested class.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 questions in 1 post:

1. It's never safe to use inner class without declaring it as `static`. It's not limited to just Android but applicable to the whole Java world.

More detailed explanation [here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3526554/avoid-memory-leaks-in-inner-classes.html)

Examples of common inner classes to check whether you are using `static class InnerAdapter` or just `class InnerAdapter` are lists (`ListView` or `RecyclerView`, tab + page layout (`ViewPager`), dropdown and **AsyncTask subclasses**

2. Doesn't matter whether you use Handler + Runnable, AsyncTask, RxJava or whatever else, if the operation completes after the Activity/ Fragment/ View is destroyed, you'd create a rouge reference of the Activity/ Fragment/ View object (which are huge) that cannot garbage collected (memory slots that cannot be freed)

So make sure to cancel those long-running task in `onDestroy()` or earlier and there would be no memory leak

Answer (score 2):

As long as you know your inner(anonymous) classes have shorter or exact the same lifecycle of the outer class, you can safely use them.

For example, you use `setOnClickListener()` for Android buttons, most of the time you use anonymous class, because there is no other object holding the reference to it, and you won't do some long process inside the listener. Once the outer class is destroyed, the inner class also can be destroyed.

[image]

Another example has memory leak issue is Android `LocationCallback` as blow example.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initLocationLibraries();
  }

  private void initLocationLibraries() {
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);

    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            // location is received
            mCurrentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            updateLocationUI();
        }
    };

    mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
  }
}
```

Now not only Activity holds the reference of LocationCallback, Android GMS service also holds it. GMS service has much longer lifecycle than Activity. It will cause memory leak to the activity.
[image]

More details are explained [here](https://medium.com/@weidianhuang/how-to-avoid-memory-leak-android-and-jvm-languages-b5283c58fe1f).