# Add 2 implements to a java class?

Tags: java, android

How do I implement two interfaces in a class like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RewardedVideoAdListener implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
}
```

If it's impossible, what's the simplest workaround?

Comment: @randnum-1 It is possible with interfaces.

Comment: It is possible. Stop misguiding him :@

Comment: @randnum-1 who is asking about multiple inheritance?

Comment: Consider whether implementing two interfaces is the right thing here anyway: *is* `MainActivity` a `RewardedVideoAdListener`, or does it merely *have* a `RewardedVideoAdListener`? You could just create inner classes for the two types of listener. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540013/declaring-that-a-class-implements-onclicklistener-vs-declaring-it-yourself).

Comment: @AndyTurner Understood. Please give an answer with examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RewardedVideoAdListener ,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
}
```

Use a comma instead of implements.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can just separate the classes it implements with commas rather than multiple `implements` keywords

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
   implements RewardedVideoAdListener, ConnectionCallbacks { }
```

Comment: @DanielNugent the way I read seemed like activity was the one implementing the interfaces, but I changed it back :)