# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-context

I have an `Activity`, which itself has three `Fragment`s.

In one of these fragments, there is a `RecyclerView` with a custom adapter, and clicking on one of its items would go to another page, which is a new instance of the same `Activity`. However, a certain behaviour causes an error in my app.

From my Activity, clicking on one of the items brings up the new instance of the same Activity, which is fine. Then I press the back button and I am taken back to the first Activity. But clicking on one of these items again (to launch a new instance of the same Activity) causes the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

It is also important to consider that I am calling the new instance of the Activity (i.e. where the three items are), in one of the fragments I have in my Activity. So, when I am calling it, I have something like:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.detail_viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.detail_tabs);
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(
                ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.text_white_secondary),
                ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.text_white));
        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    }

    ...

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: return new MainFragment();
                case 1: return new MyFragment();
                case 2: return new MyOtherFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.tab_main_frag).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.tab_my_frag).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.tab_my_other_frag).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    ...

    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyRVAdapter.OnEntryClickListener {

        ...

        private ArrayList<ItemObj> mArrayList;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ...
            doStuff();
            ...
        }

        private void doStuff() {
            ...
            mArrayList = ...;
            MyRVAdapter adapter = new MyRVAdapter(getActivity(), mArrayList);
            adapter.setOnEntryClickListener(new MyRVAdapter.OnEntryClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEntryClick(View view, int position) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("INFORMATION", mArrayList.get(position));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        ...

    }

    ...
}
```

And here is part of my custom adapter:

```
public class MyRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRVAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ...

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // The user may not set a click listener for list items, in which case our listener
            // will be null, so we need to check for this
            if (mOnEntryClickListener != null) {
                mOnEntryClickListener.onEntryClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
            }
        }
    }

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ItemObj> mArray;

    public MyRVAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemObj> array) {
        mContext = context;
        mArray = array;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tile_simple, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemObj anItem = mArray.get(position);

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }


    private static OnEntryClickListener mOnEntryClickListener;

    public interface OnEntryClickListener {
        void onEntryClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public void setOnEntryClickListener(OnEntryClickListener onEntryClickListener) {
        mOnEntryClickListener = onEntryClickListener;
    }

}
```

Here is the error in full:

```
01-23 14:07:59.083 388-388/com.mycompany.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mycompany.myapp, PID: 388
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4570)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.MyActivity$MyFragment$1.onEntryClick(MyActivity.java:783)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.adapter.MyRVAdapter$MyViewHolder.onClick(MyRVAdapter.java:42)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

The error points to the first line: `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class);` (from the fragment) first, with line after (in the error) pointing to `mOnEntryClickListener.onEntryClick(v, getLayoutPosition());` from the overriden `onClick` method in the custom adapter.

I have also read similar answers, but they have not solved my issue.

**Edit:**

By using:

```
if (getActivity() == null) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Activity context is null");
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("INFORMATION", mArrayList.get(position));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

in the inner class (`onEntryClick`) in the fragment, I found that calling `getActivity()` returns `null`.

Comment: Likely the `getActivity()` is returning null. Where are you setting your `OnClickListener`?

Comment: please add java code and - not necessary - the problem is in code

Comment: It almost sounds like you are using the same Fragment, but with a new Activity, so when it goes to get the Activity reference, it's no longer there. Are you using a retained Fragment by any chance, or are you passing a Fragment reference to the new instance of the Activity? We'll probably need to see some code to make any sense of this.

Comment: What I think it occurring is that the `OnClickListener` is encapsulating the original fragment. Without seeing where the `OnClickListener` is set though I can't really say for certain.

Comment: @CoryCharlton The `OnClickListener` is called in a `Fragment` in my `Activity`.

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh understood, but where? `onCreate`? `onCreateView`? Edit your post to include the code where you are setting the `OnClickListener` and we might be able to diagnose further.

Comment: @CoryCharlton Fair point - see my updated answer.

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh see my answer below. Might not be that simple but it's a simple test :)

Comment: @MsYvette See my updated answer.

Comment: Post the code related to Fragment creation from Activity. By the why, why did you declare 'static' the fragment class?

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli Sure, I'll post my answer when I get home (at school now). I declared the fragment `static` because that's how I learnt to use them.

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli I've updated my answer.

Comment: Did you try to replace getActivity() by MyActivity.this ?
I think you are now on the context of MyRVAdapter.OnEntryClickListener, so sometimes AndroidOs will not return the value for getActivity() as you expected.

And additional for a question that do you have any specific configuration for you Activity in the Manifest?

Comment: @PhanDinhThai I have tried that, but `MyActivity.this` cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: There are many things to review in your code. But I would start from the click listener. Could you consider to use this [utility class](http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/) in order to implement the click listener on the items? Probably there is something to fix inside the fragment but you should disclose more code.

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli There's nothing else in my fragment that would be related to this - do you have anything in particular in mind? I had also updated my answer to show how the fragments are created. I would rather not use a utilities library, because the `OnClickListener` in the `RecyclerView` `Adapter ` does the same thing. I might try including the `OnClickListener` code in the adapter itself rather than in the fragment, but I doubt this would make a difference. My suspicion is that the problem lies at `getActivity()`, but then again, I'm the one asking the question... ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, the issue is this line

```
private static OnEntryClickListener mOnEntryClickListener;
```

Since it is static you have a single instance of the class at runtime. When you click on an item, a second instance of the same Activity is created, and another instance of `mOnEntryClickListener` is created too, overwriting the previous one. So, when you press back to return to the first instance of the Activity, you are using the instance of `mOnEntryClickListener` of the second Activity, that has been destroyed.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem, but I also had to remove `static` from my `ViewHolder` as well. I also read up on this particular issue of static inner classes, and found [a great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10968689/4230345) about memory leaks and static/inner classes.

Comment: can you please help me to fix this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51405397/cannot-solve-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-java-lang-string-android-content @MimmoGrottoli

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh actually there is no reason that you would need to remove `static` from your `Viewholder` declaration. A `Viewholder` should be a `static class`, ie: just a data container with no behaviour (methods). If you are adding methods to a `Viewholder` that force you to remove the `static` modifier from the `class` definition, it means that each and every `Viewholder` object now has a reference to the outer class (in this case, the adapter). This is a waste of storage and means that your architecture is flawed. Just sayin'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely related to your anonymous `OnClickListener` capturing the `getActivity()` method from the original fragment. You could try implementing the `OnClickListener` on your `MyFragment` and see if the behavior changes at all (might not be that simple):

```
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    ...

    private void doStuff() {
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("INFORMATION", value);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    ...

}
```

---

**Edit:** This is a hack and not something I would generally recommend but may get you around the problem if you're in a pinch...

Extend the `Application` to provide a static application instance:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication _instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        _instance = this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Modify your AndroidManifest.xml so your application runs the `MyApplication`:

```
<application
    android:name="com.package.MyApplication"
<!-- Rest of your manifest -->
```

Then replace `getActivity()` with a call to `MyApplication.getInstance()`:

```
private void doStuff() {
    ...
    mArrayList = ...;
    MyRVAdapter adapter = new MyRVAdapter(getActivity(), mArrayList);
    adapter.setOnEntryClickListener(new MyRVAdapter.OnEntryClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEntryClick(View view, int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyApplication.getInstance(), MyActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("INFORMATION", mArrayList.get(position));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To be honest, for me right now it's almost midnight, so I'll get some sleep and test it out tomorrow. ;)

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me. However, I mentioned in my answer that I have buttons which, when clicked, open the Activity. But I'm actually using a `RecyclerView` with a custom adapter I made, and the Activity is opened when I click on an item from that. The issue may be in the adapter because when I tested something what I had before with three buttons instead of the RecyclerView and adapter, it worked fine. The reason I didn't mention it before is that I assumed there would not be an issue with the adapter, so not including it would have made a simpler question.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I'm not sure if it helps, but I thought I might as well include the custom adapter if the problem is there.

Comment: The problem likely is, sort of, there. Where do you set your `OnEntryClickListener`?

Comment: Sorry - see my updated answer (I forgot to include it previously).

Comment: Ok so then I assume that when you said "Your solution didn't work for me." that means that you tried to implement `OnEntryClickListener` on the fragment and replaced the anonymous method with `this` in your `adapter.setOnEntryClickListener()` in `doStuff()?

Comment: Ok I provided a hack that might work as I've got nothing at this point :)

Comment: That solved that particular error, but resulted in a different one: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MyFragment{18a42f07} not attached to Activity`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101224/discussion-between-cory-charlton-and-farbod-salamat-zadeh).

Answer (score 0):

try to use my solution:
in your MyActivity, create a new function:

```
public void openAnotherActivity(ObjectItem item) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(MyApplication.getInstance(), MyActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("INFORMATION", item);
      startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then modify doStuff() as :

```
    private void doStuff() {
    ...
    mArrayList = ...;
    MyRVAdapter adapter = new MyRVAdapter(getActivity(), mArrayList);
    adapter.setOnEntryClickListener(new MyRVAdapter.OnEntryClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEntryClick(View view, int position) {
            openAnotherActivity(mArrayList.get(position))
        }
    });
}
```

I'm not sure it can help you or not but I think at least it can resolve the `context` problem

Comment: I can't reference `openAnotherActivity` (non-static context) from a static context. Also, is `MyApplication.getInstance()` meant to be from the other answer.

Comment: So I think the problem is the static context. Why do you need to make the Holder as the static class while it can be in a normal context

Answer (score 0):

In the oncreate of your fragment, hold reference of your activity and check if your activity is in resumed state before launching other activity.

```
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyRVAdapter.OnEntryClickListener {

    ...

    private ArrayList<ItemObj> mArrayList;
    private MyActivity mActivity;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         mActivity = getActivity();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        doStuff();
        ...
    }

    private void doStuff() {
        ...
        mArrayList = ...;
        MyRVAdapter adapter = new MyRVAdapter(getActivity(), mArrayList);
        adapter.setOnEntryClickListener(new MyRVAdapter.OnEntryClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEntryClick(View view, int position) {
                if (!mActivity.isFinishing() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, MyActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("INFORMATION", mArrayList.get(position));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment create a variable of type Your Activity:

`public MainActivity activity;`

Then use the method on attach and assigns the vale:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

Then use your intent with the activity as a context:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(activity, MyActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if the problem is already solved, I want to say what my problem is and my solution.

**Problem**

In my code I have added a listener with `firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(listener)`, so when the user does the login and the new activity starts, the `listener` is executed and causes the error (because inside I have another `startActivity(getContext(), ...)`).

**Solution**

Use the method `firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(listener)` passing the listener's reference and that solves the problem. You have to remove the reference before starting the activity that causes the problem.