# RecyclerView RecyclerViewDataObserver was not registered

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, greenrobot-eventbus

Im working with `RecyclerView`, `SyncAdapter` and [greenrobot eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)
When my `SyncAdapter` finished syincing i post a message into the message bus:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventMessagesRefreshed());
```

In my target class i do the following:

```
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(EventMessagesRefreshed event) {
    this.init();
}
```

And in my `init()` i create the adapter for the recyclerview and set it:

```
public void init() {
    if(this.listRowParent != null) {
        this.adapter = new FragmentMessagesListAdapter(this.getActivity(), SingletonMessages.getInstance().getMessages());
        this.listRowParent.setAdapter(this.adapter);
    }
}

// listRowParent is my RecyclerView!
```

The fragment which receives the event is inside a of a  tab view. So there are multiple tabs and sometimes ofcourse the `SyncAdapter` posts the `EventMessagesRefreshed` into the message bus when im not in the correct target tab but since it is registered it tries to call `init()` and to create the adapter and set it to the `RecyclerView`. If that happens i get the following error:

```
Could not dispatch event: class EventMessagesRefreshed to subscribing class class FragmentMessagesList
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observer android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerViewDataObserver@2c3421a7 was not registered.
    at android.database.Observable.unregisterObserver(Observable.java:69)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.unregisterAdapterDataObserver(RecyclerView.java:5688)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapterInternal(RecyclerView.java:873)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(RecyclerView.java:857)
```

So i need to `init()` my adapter and `RecyclerView` only when the `RecyclerViewDataObserver` is registered.

**How can i do that?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to register Data observer to listen to data changes from sync adapter.

`mRecyclerViewAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(myObserver);`

RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver are a result of which notify methods you call. So for instance if you call notifyItemInserted() after you add an item to your adapter then onItemRangeInserted() will get called

A more detailed example

```
protected void setupRecyclerView() {
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mItemList);
    mAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            checkAdapterIsEmpty();
        }
    });

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    checkAdapterIsEmpty();
}`
```

> The adapter may publish a variety of events describing specific
>   changes. Not all adapters may support all change types and some may
>   fall back to a generic "something changed" event if more specific data
>   is not available.

Comment: should we unregister after using this ?

Comment: Yes, you should. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864853/when-exactly-is-it-leak-safe-to-use-anonymous-inner-classes

Comment: @crgarridos how to unregister, link you posted doesn't answer that question

Comment: It still helps in 2023. Thanks for the example.

Comment: @crgarridos: The link you referred to doesn't seem to have any code to unregister an AdapterDataObserver. Am I missing something?