# Android Custom listview is very slow despite using best practices

Tags: android, image, listview

I am programming a VR Android application and using a custom listview to display images to the user. The listview, for whatever reason, is incredibly laggy when scrolling. I've looked over many tutorials on how to speed up the listview but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried decreasing the size of the imagebuttons, disabled the scroll cache, and many other things. Note: I don't think the problem is the picasso call, because when I comment it out, it is still slow when scrolling.

My XML for the custom layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="170dp"
android:padding="10dp">
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/redirect_btn"
    android:longClickable="false"
 />


</LinearLayout>
```

The code for the custom listview is here:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private Activity activity;
private String[] listOfVideoNames;
private String[] listOfVideoTileImageURLs;
private VrVideoInfo[] listOfVrVideoInfo;
private Context context;

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public MyCustomAdapter(String[] listOfVideoNames, String[] listOfVideoTileImages, VrVideoInfo[] vrList, Activity activity, Context context) {
    this.listOfVideoNames = listOfVideoNames;
    listOfVideoTileImageURLs = listOfVideoTileImages;
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
    listOfVrVideoInfo = vrList;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listOfVideoNames.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem (int pos) {
    return listOfVideoNames[pos];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return 0;
    // return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable
}
public class Holder {
    ImageButton imageButton;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Holder holder;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new Holder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_layout, parent, false);
        holder.imageButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.redirect_btn);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else
    {
        holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    Picasso.with(context).load(listOfVideoTileImageURLs[position])
    .into(holder.imageButton);
    holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, VideoViewer.class);
            intent.putExtra("video_title", listOfVideoNames[position]);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

and just in case it is relevant, here is what calls the custom listview:

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

// string adapter that will handle the data of the list view
MyCustomAdapter adapter;
String[] vrVideoTitles = null;

String[] videoTileImageListURLs = null;
ArrayList<VrVideoInfo> videoInfo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_activity);


    videoInfo = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("rData");
    vrVideoTitles = new String[videoInfo.size()];
    videoTileImageListURLs = new String[videoInfo.size()];




    for (int i = 0; i < videoInfo.size(); i++) {
        vrVideoTitles[i] = videoInfo.get(i).GetTitle();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < videoInfo.size(); i++)
    {
        videoTileImageListURLs[i] = videoInfo.get(i).GetImageURl();
    }

    VrVideoInfo[] info = videoInfo.toArray(new VrVideoInfo[videoInfo.size()]);

    //instantiate custom adapter
    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(vrVideoTitles,    
    videoTileImageListURLs,info, this, this);

    //handle listview and assign adapter
    ListView lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_container);
    lView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    lView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
    lView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    lView.setAdapter(adapter);
}



}
```

Any information or tips would be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Are the images different sizes?

Comment: @EugeneH The images are all the same size. When I comment out the picasso line, it still lags.

Comment: have you tried removing this line lView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

Comment: Did you try profilling your app? https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html

Comment: @NIPHIN I actually added that to try to speed it up, so unfortunately, removing that didn't work. I will try profiling my app and see what I get.

Comment: comment out `holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener` and try again

Comment: @pskink I did that and unfortunately, nothing improved. It seems that just using the list adapter without any calls to anything makes it lag.

Comment: @BrandanJablonski impossible, how many times `if(convertView == null)` is called? is it ten or so?

Comment: @pskink It is called  5 times.

Comment: can you for testing use ArrayAdapter?

Comment: @pskink Just tried the switch and still nothing. It's almost the same as before, maybe a little bit better. But it's not at all what I would call smooth.

Comment: you have any background threads maybe? come on simple arrayadapter cannot lag

Comment: That's why I asked this question. Before I go to the listview, I am using a runnable and a AsyncTask to load data, but I finish the activity so I assume that I've gotten rid of them both...

Comment: what does traceview say? refer to Zielony's comment

Answer (score 0):

make your viewholder static, non-static inner classes also have reference to their containing class and it is not a memory efficient implementation.

Comment: :D, nice please add a comment specifying the reason for downvote.
reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864853/when-exactly-is-it-leak-safe-to-use-anonymous-inner-classes
https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: it will not improve the performance at all. how many `Holder` objects do you expect to be created? do you know what is the size in bytes of each `Holder` instance? making it "static" just removes one reference per each `Holder` instance, BTW the OP should not use that "holder" stuff at all as in 99% cases it just make the code more complex and has no performance impact

Comment: Viewholder pattern is used to avoid expensive findviewbyid() operation, so using holder pattern definitely improves performance

Comment: [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) you have all google's adapters extending `BaseAdapter`, please show me at least one that uses holder pattern, if you do that i will agree the holder pattern is usefull, also when we are talking about `findViewById` see [this](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2013/11/is-findviewbyid-slow.html)

Comment: please refer to https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html . In fact the new listing solution Recyclerview have incorporated this technique in its architecture.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html .

Comment: again, is there any google's `BaseAdapter` that uses it? no, there is not, some time ago i made some measurements and when using holder pattern i saved 1ms or so when scrolling 1000 items list view from the top to the bottom, **ONE millisecond**, does it pay off? definitely no, at least in majority of cases

Comment: do a fast scrolling and see the difference it causes with your own eye, when such operation are performed findviewbyid are really a bottle neck especially if the list item viewgroup has multiple child elements.

Comment: i did the measurements of `findviewbyid`, and as i said i saved **0.001 second**, what my eye can do in 1ms? just call findviewbyid 1000 times (not in a loop but side by side) and measure the time spent and you will see, did you see the results [here](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2013/11/is-findviewbyid-slow.html)?

Comment: I made the viewholder static but I don't see an increase in speed unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after awhile. Apparently, another intern where I'm working put an image view on top of the list view and I didn't see it because he set it to be transparent. So in other words, don't put image views on top of list views.