# Create a map with key and value in one line in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

Is there a way to create a map with keys and values at the same time (I mean a one-line code)? For example, I create a map named map, and I need to use the method "put" whenever I want to add a new pair of key/value. Is there a shorter way to populate a map when we create it?

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("A", "32");
    map.put("C", "34");
    map.put("T", "53");
```

Comment: What's the value of doing something in one line ? Readability ? No. Maintainability ? No. Performance ? No.

Comment: Just for fun, no?

Comment: @Andremoniy I can think about many other things that will be more fun, but that's primarily opinion based ;)

Comment: What's stopping you from putting it all on one line?

Comment: @alfasin One value would be if you needed to pass as a parameter, or return a map from a lambda. E.g., `configure(Map.of("width", 640, "height", 480))` Any place you would want to write it as an expression, in other words.

Comment: @DavidConrad that's exactly the purpose of `of()` method - to *not* do everything in one line but rather have another method that does it for you, while keeping the code concise without compromising its readability!

Answer (score 18):

## Convenience Factory Methods for Collections

In [Java 9](https://jdk9.java.net/download/) there are some [new Map helper methods](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) defined by [*JEP 269: Convenience Factory Methods for Collections*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269).

```java
Map<String, String> map = Map.of(
    "A", "32", 
    "C", "34", 
    "T", "53"
);
```

But this only works for up to 10 entries. For more than ten, use:

```java
import static java.util.Map.entry;

Map<String, String> map = Map.ofEntries(
    entry("A", "32"), 
    entry("C", "34"), 
    entry("T", "53")
);
```

You could write similar helper methods if you needed to do it in earlier versions.

Answer (score 12):

In Java 8 you can use the following methods which are [explained here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200919175407/https://www.amitph.com/create-hashmap-in-java/):

#### If you just need a quick immutable single-entry or empty map

```java
Map<String, String> map = Collections.singletonMap("A", "32");
```

```java
Map<String, String> map = Collections.emptyMap();
```

#### Using Streams

Suppose you have your data in an `ArrayList` of objects that contain your `Data` that can be accessed with arbitrary getters, you can use the Streams API:

```java
List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
// .... populate data list
Map<String, Integer> nameToAge = dataList.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Data::getFooAsKey, Data::getBarAsValue)
);
```

...or using an inline map approach (if you don't have/need/want to create `dataList`):

```java
Map<String, Integer> map = Stream.of( 
    new Data("A", "32"), new Data("C", "34"), new Data("C", "34")
).collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getFooAsKey, User::getBarAsValue));
```

#### Anonymous Subclass (discouraged)

```java
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("A", "32");
    put("C", "34");
    put("T", "53");
}};
```

As this method [can cause memory leaks](https://web.archive.org/save/https://www.jesperdj.com/2016/07/19/dont-use-the-double-brace-initialization-trick/) it is strongly discouraged.

#### Using Guava

```java
Map<String, String> immutableMap = Maps.newHashMap(
    ImmutableMap.of("A", "32", "C", "34", "T", "53")
);
```

Starting with Java 9 there's superior syntactic sugar available, as outlined in [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101234/create-a-map-with-key-and-value-in-one-line-in-java/67928645#answer-42101677).

Comment: Cool! Could you provide, more details about memory leaks in Anonymous Subclass implementation. please?

Comment: @stanley Basically all non-static inner classes bear the potential to cause memory leaks b/c of the way the GC works, as explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864853/). Regarding the anonymous subclass initialization trick, asking ecosia / google returns a number of writeups on this, for example [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20210226184817/https://jesperdj.com/2016/07/19/dont-use-the-double-brace-initialization-trick/) (i have linked that in the answer now).

Comment: Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("A", "32");
    put("C", "34");
    put("T", "53");
}};  works

Comment: @gli00001 sure it does, but nevertheless it's a nefarious idea, unless you like living on the edge (of hunting memory leaks in your application) – please read the linked articles on this and choose wisely. The best choice of course is and will always be to go to Java 9+ where you can simply do `Map.of(key, value)`.

Comment: thanks  Philzen, I meant to show there was syntax err in the original 
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>({{
    put("A", "32");
    put("C", "34");
    put("T", "53");
}});

Comment: @gli00001 oh i see now – thanks for this, i've updated the answer accordingly!